# How to narrow `snapshot` inside `FutureBuilder.builder()` without using null-check (!)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

### Problem

I am currently learning Flutter and familiar with TS. While Flutter/Dart is known for being strongly-typed, I'm encountering difficulties trying to narrowing down my nullable types (which would be possible in TS).

Specifically, I used `FutureBuilder` and an async function to fetch data, and tried to build widgets based on those data. The data is `List<{ path: String, ... }>` for brevity. However, I cannot access `snapshot.data`:

[image: Problem]

My approach looks dumb. I looked up the docs and the closest solution I found to my problem is [type promotion](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#type-promotion-on-null-checks), but I believe this is not what I'm looking for.

### Code

```dart
child: FutureBuilder(
    future: _selectedImages,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // error: dart(unchecked_use_of_nullable_value)
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
            log(snapshot.data[0].path);
        }

        // error: dart(unchecked_use_of_nullable_value)
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.isNotEmpty) {
            log(snapshot.data[0].path);
        }

        // this works
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final tmp = snapshot.data?[0].path;
            if (tmp != null) {
                log(tmp);
            }
        }
    },
),
```

### Editted for @pskink

I believe I covered all the cases, why the errors still pop up, do you know why ?

[image: pskink]

```dart
                // this works
                // builder: ((context, snapshot) =>
                //     switch ((snapshot.connectionState, snapshot.data)) {
                //       // TODO: Handle this case.
                //       (ConnectionState.none, _) =>
                //         Text('null ${snapshot.data.toString()}'),
                //       (ConnectionState.waiting, _) => const Text('text'),
                //       (ConnectionState.active, _) => const Text('text'),
                //       (ConnectionState.done, null) => const Text('text'),
                //       (ConnectionState.done, final data?) => const Text('text'),
                //     }),

                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch ((snapshot.connectionState, snapshot.data)) {
                    case (ConnectionState.none, _):
                      return Text('null ${snapshot.data.toString()}');
                    case (ConnectionState.waiting, _):
                      return const Text('text');
                    case (ConnectionState.active, _):
                      return const Text('text');
                    case (ConnectionState.done, null):
                      return const Text('text');
                    case (ConnectionState.done, final data?):
                      return const Text('text');
                    // no error if have this
                    // default:
                    //   return const Text('text');
                  }
                }
```

Comment: You need to be sure that data will not come null and you can cast in FutureBuilder

Comment: Better use pattern matching, something like https://twitter.com/SandroMaglione/status/1750907785452069333/photo/1

Comment: Post this function as well _selectedImages

Comment: @pskink In your example, how is it possible that he doesn't declare the default case, yet the code still run ?

Comment: "how is it possible that he doesn't declare the default case, yet the code still run ?" - see https://dart.dev/language/branches#exhaustiveness-checking

Comment: @pskink Can i assume only switch case using arrow functions is able to do this, as I try to rewrite it without arrow func, I have to verbosely declare the default case. I could post the code if you want to see.

Comment: @pskink Can I reason like this: in switch expressions, Dart know for sure I cover all my cases because of `ConnectionState` is an enum, so `default` case will never happen and redundant -> don't need to write it. But in verbose case without the `=>`, I have to write `default` case everytime I use switch, because Dart don't know anything ?

Comment: ok if you *know* that you cover all the cases then you dont need `default` - why do you say you have to write `default`?

Comment: for example: `void main() {
print('start');
dynamic a = 1;
switch (a) {
case 1: print('=== 1');
case 2: print('=== 2');
}
print('end');
}`

Comment: i see it now, the `switch` works the different way if you use `int` vs `bool` or any enum, i dont know why to be honest... did you try to ask chatgpt or bard.ggogle.com? sometimes they have good advices...

Comment: @pskink It's ok. Your advice helps me 90% to find what I need (not using this `!`). I will try to write a new answer later. The reason I wanna avoid using `=>` is just for me to practice as a beginner. Thanks for all your help so far. Editted: yes, i tried asking chatgpt, but not much helps, sadly. Editted 2nd time: lol

Comment: hehehe i tried bard.google.com - the same nonsense... ;-) btw did you find `switch ()` more practical inside `FutureBuilder.builder` than the cascades of `if`s?

Comment: yeah, it covered much more expected values, so I think using `switch` is more appropriate than chaining `if`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`snapshot.hasData` already mean that `snapshot.data != null`. You can look at source code of `async.dart` file:

> bool get hasData => data != null;

But unfortunately, Dart Analytic doesn't have enough smart to know about a param inside a class isn't null like that.

Dart can only promote local variables to null safety.
The field `data` of an AsyncSnapshot object can theoretically return anything the next time you read it, so it can't be promoted based on checking that the value you read in one place is not null.
Even if that data is final and cannot be setter but promoted, it means that the author can’t change that field in the future.
So, promotion is only for local variables.

If you want a quick fix then you can just put ! behind the data after you check `snapshot.hasData` and it will be fine:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
   final data = snapshot.data!;
   // from here data can use without null error
}
```

And below is some code I usually use with FutureBuilder:

```
    FutureBuilder(
      future: _selectedImages,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final data = snapshot.data;
        
        if (data == null) {
          return YourLoadingWidget();
        }

        // do whatever you want with non-nullable data here

      },
    )
```

Comment: Yeah, the first part you mentioned is exactly what I would like to express. If I recall correctly, TS could infer types within the scope block based on `if (logicHere)`, acting like a type guard or control flow analysis. We could then access values confidently, as TypeScript ensured they wouldn't be null, thus avoiding any squiggly lines. Do you happen to know of any links or resources discussing the limitations of Dart Analytics, as you mentioned ?

Comment: I don’t really have a document about Dart Analytic, but you can understand it's a design decision. Dart can only promote local variables to null safety.
The field data of a AsyncSnapshot object can theoretically return anything the next time you read it, so it can't be promoted based on checking that the value you read in one place is not null.
Even if that data is Final and cannot be setter, but promoted it mean that author can’t change that field in the future
So, promotion is only for local variables

Comment: There is a conversation about this here https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1722